# TFS testcase are not displayed on story board even story are tested by testcase

Tags: azure-devops

1) For TFS 2018 and VSTS, the user can create testcase directly on story board. and test cases created here are automatically linked by story with 'test by' relationship.  and they can be viewed on testcase part.

[create one testcase for linked user story on test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDTJe.png)

2) however, the testcase created or linked to story on testcase part, can't be displayed on story board, why?
[the existing testcase is not displayed on story board. try to create a testcase directly on board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnJRq.png)

3) some tricky, though the testcase are not displayed on storyborad, then when you create a testcase for user story with existing linked testcases, then all linked testcase are displayed on story board?

[the existing testcase created on test are displayed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RQ4z.png)
it is work as designed? I am confused. I think if the testcase is linked to story with test relationship, it should be displayed on story borad.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue? What's the result like? Can you provide the screenshot? What's the result if you using another internet browser or on other machine?

Comment: I tried with Edge and chrome. both can reproduce it. please try the steps as below; 1) create a new user story on story kanban 2) Go to testplan, set up a new test plan. and add test suite based on requirement. select the user story you just create. and create a testcase for it. 3) go back to userstory kanban, check the userstory, there is no testcase displayed on the kanban. 4) create a testcase for userstory directly on kanban, then , 2 testcases are dispalyed within the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, can reproduce this issue too, submitted a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submit an issue here:[Story board issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/230127/story-board-issue.html) that you can follow.

Comment: thanks.  and I am some confused, which TFS question should go to stackoverflow. which questions should go to developercommmunity.visualstudio.com. it seems stackoverflow answers questions more timely than developercommunity.

Comment: @zhuang The developer community forum is used to report bug instead of deal with question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's closed, but just to let everyone know. This is kind of weird, but it's not the relation that makes the test appear, it's the fact that it is present in the test plan within a "Requirement based suite". Any other test case won't ever appear on the board. When you create a new test from the board (or from test plan with the correct Suite type) this will cause the other tests to appear as well since the requirement suite will be created. The related tests links will be automatically added to the suite end because of that the board will display them.